# POSIX issue with mingw (sem_timedwait)

Tags: time, operating-system, posix, semaphore

I’m using mingw:

> GNU Make 4.1
>
> Built for x86_64-w64-mingw32

I have noticed that sem_timedwait isn't functional (it returns -1).
I have no issue with sem_wait or sem_signal.

Code example:

```
struct timespec timeSpec;
int   rc = 0;
timeSpec.tv_sec = 1000;
timeSpec.tv_nsec = 0;
rc = sem_timedwait(pSemId,&timeSpec);
```

> CC= x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc

Comment: And what is `errno` set to?

Comment: printf ("%s", strerror(errno)) --> "Unknown error"
"Unknown error" is the result of errno

Comment: The actual numerical value of the `errno` would have been more helpful, since `strerror()` isn't guaranteed to have a description for every possible one. And some descriptions are outright confusing. Armed with the `errno` you can check the Mingw headers to see what error the code corresponds to. That should help narrow down your search for the problem.

Comment: printf("%d", errno) --> 138
error.h:

#define ETIMEDOUT 138

but absolutely no timeout occurred!

Comment: Simple Google of `"mingw" "sem_timedwait" "errno" "138"` reveals: `#define ETIMEDOUT 138`. I hope you can guess the rest. ;)

Comment: no timeout occurred! i set 10000sec but it didn't wait even 1nanosec

Comment: Try shorter timeout. Some implementations pose an upper  limit on how long you can wait. (And search your own Mingw installation for the `138`: the raw error codes are not portable. (See the pthread.h file.))

Comment: ETIMEDOUT is 138 (pthread.h). timer=1sec also isn't functional.

Answer (score 2):

ok, 
time should be relative and not absolote.
    tm = time(NULL);
    timeSpec.tv_sec = tm+10;
    timeSpec.tv_nsec = 0;
    rc = sem_timedwait(pSemId,&timeSpec);

It solve the problem.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem! Pretty retarded to use the absolute time where every other similar function uses the relative time.